# Не запускается приложени Android Studio

Tags: android

После того как я добавил код в MainActivity.java в метод OnCreate, BottomNavigationView приложение перестало запускается ошибок не выдаёт. В чём проблема?

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        BottomNavigationView bottomNav = findViewById(R.id.bottom_nav_prapor);
        bottomNav.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(navListener);
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.nav_news, R.id.nav_keys, R.id.nav_rounds, R.id.nav_exits,
                R.id.nav_maps, R.id.nav_questions, R.id.nav_characters, R.id.nav_items, R.id.nav_traders)
                .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
                .build();
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);

        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment,
                new TpraporFragment()).commit();

    }
    private  BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener navListener =
            new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
                    Fragment selectedFragment = null;

                    switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                        case R.id.nav_lvl1:
                            selectedFragment = new TpraporFragment();
                            break;
                        case R.id.nav_lvl2:
                            selectedFragment = new TpraporFragmentlvl2();
                            break;
                        case R.id.nav_lvl3:
                            selectedFragment = new TpraporFragmentlvl3();
                            break;
                        case R.id.nav_crown:
                            selectedFragment = new TpraporFragmentlvl4();
                            break;
                    }
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container
                            ,
                            selectedFragment).commit();

                    return true;
                }
            };
```

Comment: но хоть что-то пишет в логах касательно приложения?? само оно не случилось))

Comment: Юрий, нет, компилируется как надо, в логах всё в порядке ошибок нет а когда на телефоне запускаешь он просто как будто начинает открывается после чего моментально закрывается.

Comment: значит подключите телефон к пк и посмотрите в чем проблема, если моментально закрывается, то значит есть ошибка

Comment: Так я и так через телефон пробовал

Comment: а телефон подключен к пк?

Comment: НЕТ ПО ВАЙ ФАЙ. Естественно подключён напрямую